# Sharepoint bug database - any good?

Tags: sharepoint, bug-tracking

We've been using Sharepoint as a poor man's bug tracking database for the last couple of projects that we did.  No one is really happy with the solution so I'm looking for alternatives.  I happened to stumble upon the [Bug Database Template](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C72D23AF-F556-47AA-A6F2-0027246A9928&displaylang=en) for Sharepoint.  If it is halfway decent it might be a good choice for us since the transition would be smooth as the team is already used to Sharepoint.

Anyone have any experience using this template?  Any major problems?  Any major missing features?  Is there any documentation out there beyond that download page?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak on the Bug database itself but our users have had shown some very positive acceptance of some of the other "Fab 40" SharePoint templates (Multiple Project Budgeting, Knowledge Base, etc.)

Your best bet is to just create a pilot site using the template and have a few of your people check it out.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the info.  Yeah I know I should set up a test site.  But in the corporate environment I find myself, provisioning that kind of setup would take a sadly large amount of effort.  So I wanted to try to gauge if it was worth it first.

Comment: Or spin up a VM and try it.  It is super easy.

Comment: Accepting this answer.  Doesn't look like I'm going to get any specific info on the bug database.

Answer (score 2):

**Stop struggling against the tide, [bite the bullet and get TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364062(VS.80).aspx) - or something similar.** *:-)*

Given the historic challenges of using Sharepoint for workflow, and its (in)ability to effectively organize, manage, report, and summarize information - you're unlikely to see a dramatic step forward with the bug template. You may find some things a bit easier, but for the most part, I expect you will continue to be unhappy with Sharepoint as a bug management tool.

Comment: I completely agree.  This would be a stop gap solution until we can land on something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2012 does not have bug tracking in per se. It is managed as a work item. Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

sorry forgot to include this with my answer based on my small research - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206031/use-tfs-to-track-bugs-from-production-support